# homomorphism $l_{*}:\pi _{1}(M) \rightarrow \pi _{1}(\mathbb{RP}^{2})$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I need to describe the homomorphism $l_{*}:\pi _{1}(M) \rightarrow \pi _{1}(\mathbb{RP}^{2}) $, $M$ is a Möbius strip. I understand that $\pi _{1}(M)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi _{1}(\mathbb{RP}^{2})$ - to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Suppose $[u]\in \pi _{1}(M)$. $l_{*}([u])=?$

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It's enough to find the image of a generator, and it will be the nontrivial element of $\pi_1(\Bbb{RP}^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

It is just the map that is reduction mod $2$. To see this, consider the sphere $S^2$ and an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of the equator, let us call it $E$. After quotienting out by $x \sim -x$, $S^2$ turns into $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and $E$ gets sent to the Möbius strip $M$. Note that the image of $\pi_1(E)$ is loops that are multiples of $2$. So, any loop of multiple $2$ lifts to a loop in $E$ which is null-homotopic in $S^2$, and so projects to a null-homotopy in $\mathbb{R}P^2$. Now note that the generator in $\pi_1(M)$ maps to the generator in $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)$ by a slightly modified argument - the loop lifts to an arc from one antipode to another in $S^2$ and so projects to an essential loop in $\mathbb{R}P^2$.